# gologin sqlite3 webpack error when building

Tags: node.js, sqlite, webpack, electron, electron-builder

I'm currently building an electron app with webpack and nodej.
When i run **npm start**, it has no problem but when i build my app using **npm run package**, it shows 2 errors

```
ERROR in ./release/app/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/Find-VisualStudio.cs 9:6
[0] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:6)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I also install visual studio code 2017 and python on my windowns.
Using external sqlite3 can build success, but when running my app it shows can not find module sqlite3.

Any idea?